# I'm creating opensource GPL H264 encoding lib/app (based on x264) do I need to pay for the license?

Tags: c++, c, licensing, h.264, x264

I'm creating opensource GPL H264 encoding lib/app (based on x264) do I need to pay for the license?

Comment: what country are you in? Do you plan to visit the US anytime soon?

Comment: @kts - The patents aren't just valid in the US: http://weblogs.mozillazine.org/bz/archives/020400.html

Comment: not US but I have plans on visiting so it all needs to be clean=)

Comment: It appears that the first question, "do you need a license at all?", is already answered. That's already not really programming related. The financial terms for such a license even less so.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about licensing or legal issues, not programming or software development. [See here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/274963/questions-about-licensing/274964#274964) and [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/139804/can-licensing-questions-ever-be-on-topic) for details, and the [help] for more.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [this blog article](http://blog.christophersmart.com/2010/02/01/mpeg-la-confirms-h-264-license-needed-for-free-software-and-end-users/), the MPEG-LA specifically indicated that license fees are required even for open source software:

> In response to your specific question, under the Licenses royalties are paid on all MPEG-4 Visual/AVC products of like functionality, and the Licenses do not make any distinction for products offered for free (whether open source or otherwise)…

However, like many patent-encumbered technologies, the licensing landscape is very complex and confusing (that's what lawyers do), so it's hard to say that a 2nd hand comment from an email sent by someone in the MPEG-LA organization can be considered definitive.  If I were writing open source software, I'd probably just shy away from H.264 if at all possible (and maybe rely on system installed codec if that's an option).  If I were writing commercial software, I'd definitely get a license, either directly or indirectly by licensing a library from an outfit that had a license.

Sorry to be absolutely no help...

Comment: "the Licenses do not make any distinction for products offered for free" - Well, MPEG-LA may say that, but their license says otherwise.  Only encoder products which are *sold* need to pay royalties - the license says *sold* so this is quite explicit.  But see below, doing stuff with encoded content needs separate license.

Answer (score 2):

MPEG-LA claims the patents they license are necessary to implementing H.264. A [summary of their licensing terms](http://www.mpegla.com/main/programs/avc/Documents/AVC_TermsSummary.pdf) doesn't show an obvious exception being made just because some software happens to be free. On the other hand, all of their language talks about codecs that are "sold". My guess is that you'd just about have to get the real license agreement ([available via hardcopy only](http://www.mpegla.com/main/programs/AVC/Pages/AgreementExpress.aspx)) to come to any solid conclusions.

Answer (score 1):

As a worker in the video compression industry, I can offer my understanding (I am not a layer) that to just operate an H.264 codec legally you need a license.

Whether that is enforcible depends on how public or private you are about operating your codec.

This is the licensing organization's web site: http://www.mpegla.com/main/default.aspx

Certainly if you purchase a commercial codec, say as part of some video editing software, then you've paid for a license.  On the other hand, if you've downloaded ffmpeg and you run it without paying anything to anybody you are in violation.  If you search out a contact within the licensing oarganization to send a check to, which I don't pretend would be simple, then you could conceivably arrange a license to run ffmpeg.

Whether you can announce and/or distribute a codec you've written without arranging for those who receive your codec to also receive a license is boarderline - clearly the licensing organization wishes you to do make such arrangements.  Making an announcement is a public act, so you don't have any protection of privacy.  Ffmpeg, on the other hand, gets away with being public and not making any licensing arrangements - however they are A) a project of significant size with many people willing to support it; B) very clear that they consider any onus to be on the user and not on them.

Comment: FFmpeg does not itself encode or decode h264.  Rather it uses the x264 (and potentially libaac), which are separate and independent FOSS projects.

Comment: Also depends on your country, if you are somewhere that software patents aren't valid then the MPEGLA can say whatever they like.

Comment: To add to it, I believe (though I may be wrong) if you *compile* FFMPEG yourself, you'll need a license. If you downloaded the FFMPEG binary that was compiled and distributed by someone else, that other party is responsible for the license.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a license to write source code. MPEG-LA's opinion is that you need one to distribute it.

Answer (score 0):

You need license according to the way you planning to put in the market, In any sort of way you planning to make money out of it( like advertisements ) Then you will liable to pay to the patent holders (here x264), For more info http://www.mpegla.com/main/programs/AVC/Pages/AgreementExpress.aspx
http://weblogs.mozillazine.org/bz/archives/020400.html
 and you could get a hard copy from MPEG LA by sending details to them.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, you do, at least in the United States.

Comment: It's more complicated than that.  The Question does not indicate if distribution will include binaries or not.  Nor does it mention if this project will be from a commercial or non-profit entity.

Comment: @Stu Thompson: Err.. no, it isn't. US Patent law makes no exceptions simply because something is distributed for free. Unless MPEG-LA is making some sort of an exception, then the answer *is* that simple.